# Array mismatch in Keras classifier model output layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am designing a classifier which takes 10 values - signal (acquired by processing pixels of MNIST dataset, normalized 0-1) at the input, and outputs the class of digit. The 10 valued signal is unique for each digit and therefore classification can be performed.

```
num_classes=10
y_train=to_categorical(y_train,num_classes)
y_test=to_categorical(y_test,num_classes)


x_train=(60000,10,1,1)
y_train=(60000,10)
x_test=(10000,10,1,1)
y_test=(10000,10)
```

The code is given as

```
input_img = Input(shape=(10,1,1))
x = Flatten()(input_img)
x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
decoded = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)


autoencoder=Model(input_img,decoded)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

history=autoencoder.fit(x_train, y_train,
                epochs=30,
                batch_size=32, 
                verbose=1,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Please suggest what changes can be made.

Comment: What shape y_train has prior to fit? `y_train=(60000,10)` this one? Or you send this to `y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)` and then feed into fit?

Comment: y_train has shape (60000,10) after to_cat is applied and it is sent to fit

Comment: It's probably you're using the wrong loss function. As you made one-hot encoded vector then use `categorical_cross_entropy` loss function.

Comment: Agree with @M.Innat .See [categoricalcrossentropy](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#categoricalcrossentropy-class) and [sparsecategoricalcrossentropy](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should probably use the `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy` loss function because you encoded your target to one hot vector using `to_categorical`. According to [doc](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#categoricalcrossentropy-class):

> Use this **crossentropy loss** function when there are two or more label classes. We expect labels to be provided in a **one_hot** representation. If you want to provide **labels as integers**, please use **`SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`** loss.

However, IMO, without reproducible code, it's really ambitious to give a specific answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help, the program did work but seems like a training problem. I provided link to x_test and x_train files, and the y_train y_test can be fetched and processed by the reproducible code i posted. Can you please suggest what is missing

Comment: The training loss is increasing as can be seen from the trace attached in the original post

Comment: It's better to ask a new question if your current question is solved. Because you may face a new problem after solving the current problem which is also a new problem with your previous problem. The discussion won't lead to a conclusion.